# How can I test multiple inputs to detect negative numbers, simultaneously recording which input(s) were negative?

Tags: java, integer, int

I'm writing a short program to prompt the user for numeric inputs, which I will then test to see if they are negative and report back which ones pass this test. I'm looking for a method that avoids duplicating logic for each expected input.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Negative
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Insert three integers, USER.");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int y = scan.nextInt();
        int z = scan.nextInt();
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0)  
        {
          System.out.println("A number is negative.");
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can do each of these individually but I'd like to condense the code somehow.

Comment: If you want to know which is negative, you need to test each one individually. You can store the result of each test in a variable first.

Comment: Aw, too bad. Was hoping for a way to multitask. Thanks.

Comment: You can but it is likely to be more complicated. I suggest you break it down into simple operations.

Comment: I bet you were wondering if the `if()` statement could somehow return which condition returned a `true`. That's impossible because (not counting the short-cut operators || or &&) `if()` will combine all conditions in boolean algebra to determine if true/false

Answer (score 1):

You could always create a method that takes the *variable* `name` and `value` and then print it. Something like,

```
private static void display(String name, int val) {
    if (val >= 0) {
        System.out.printf("%s (%d) is NOT negative%n", name, val);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%s (%d) is negative%n", name, val);
    }
}
```

Then you can call `display()`,

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert three integers, USER.");
    display("x", scan.nextInt());
    display("y", scan.nextInt());
    display("z", scan.nextInt());
}
```

Now it doesn't actually store `x`, `y` or `z`. If you need them later, then you really do need

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert three integers, USER.");
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int y = scan.nextInt();
    int z = scan.nextInt();
    display("x", x);
    display("y", y);
    display("z", z);
    // do something else with x,y or z
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Google guava preconditions statements to make it cleaner.

For example the above code can be changed..

```
    import com.google.common.base.Preconditions.*;
   public class Negative
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Insert three integers, USER.");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int y = scan.nextInt();
        int z = scan.nextInt();
        Preconditions.checkArgument(x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0 ,"Negative number entered");
    }
}
```

If the argument fails, an `IllegalArgumentException`would be thrown. 
More documentation [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html)

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply applying loop until user inputs positive number :-

```
int x = scan.nextInt();
int y = scan.nextInt();
int z = scan.nextInt();
while(x<0||y<0||z<0)
{
     x = scan.nextInt();
     y = scan.nextInt();
     z = scan.nextInt();
}
```